# Need help about android layout design

Tags: android, mobile

I am begginer to android development. I want to make the similar screen in android like home tab. Here on home tab it have two view. By draging the view left or right i can move the view to show the next view. Please help me how i can make this in android. I need the details reply or some tutorial links.

Here are the screen shots. I want to make the exact same copy of this.

Screen 1

[image]

http://screencast.com/t/pJaLLHT74fH0

Screen 2

[image: http://screencast.com/t/QCaOlmVJv5sJ]

http://screencast.com/t/QCaOlmVJv5sJ

Comment: Could you please provide some more information. I'd like to help you, but I just see the text screen 1 and 2 and no links or pictures. If you want some help I need more info

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this would be to use the ViewPager class. Android's developer site has a great explanation and an example of how you would use a ViewPager here:

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

If instead you wanted to swipe between tabs, they also provide this example:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

For the circle indicators at the bottom, you can implement Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator library. You can download it and find several examples here: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have implemented the view1 and the view2. 
So, here is my solution :

```
    public class FatherLayout extends RelativeLayout  implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener, GestureDetector.OnScrollListener{
    private YourView view1 ;
    private YourView view2;

    int acitveView; // this var indicates which view is active 

    // your gesture detector here that you handle the drag events!
    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 


    public FatherLayout(Context context){
        super(context);

        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);
        mDetector.setOnScrollListener(this);
        this.addView(view2); // i assume that you want the view1 appears on the top  
        this.addView(view1);
        activeView = 1;
        invalidate();
    }



       /*Following YOUR GESTURE DETECTOR IMPLEMENTATION HERE*/
    @Override 
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){ 
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        // Be sure to call the superclass implementation
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) { 
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
            float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onFling: " + event1.toString()+event2.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onLongPress: " + event.toString()); 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
            float distanceY) {
        // HERE YOU WILL DO ALL THE JOB.
        // FOR INSTANCE IF YOU WANT TO move the view1 you will call something like this : 
        if(activeView == 1){

            view1.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
            view2.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
            activeView = 0;

        }else if(activeView == 0){
            view1.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
            view2.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
            activeView = 1;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onShowPress: " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapUp: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTapEvent: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onSingleTapConfirmed: " + event.toString());
        return false;
    }

}



}
```

Comment: thank you for all of your great help. Now i understand how to make this interface.

Comment: You welcome :) Please, mark the question as solved and vote up!